# How to restrict ListItem to be on screen even after restartLoaderManager in android?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-cursoradapter, android-loadermanager

I have a list view and m populating it `bindView` with a limit of max 25 items to be shown. I have a `Button` above the `ListView`. When i click the button, it is supposed to increase the listitems from 25 to 50 i.e. to load more 25 items.

Suppose i am on list item **`d`** now, and i click the **`Button`**, it loads the items , and works fine, but **What I want is** the list should be refreshed, as its been refreshing, but i must be on the same item as i was before. List items should be increased, but i dnt want the list to be refreshed again from the top as now after the list is being refreshed, m taken to the top of the list.

[image]

Comment: just call listviewadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: show us some code of populating listview so that i can guide you.

Comment: @android-mantra, my list data is being refreshed so as my list Views, but i just want my visible position not to be changed, just to remain there where it was before

Comment: dont set adapter once again that is what making the listview refresh.

Comment: m using LoaderManager, and in order to load data, i need to use refreshLoaderManager.

Comment: can you show me code?

Answer (score 0):

When 1st time list view created, fill the list with data i.e. 25. Again when click button for next 25 data, don't create list adapter again although use following code:

```
((BaseAdapter)adapter).notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: in order to load next 25, i must use restartLoaderManager, which ultimately gives data to bindView...

Comment: my list data is being updated as i expect, but i just need to be at same position as i was before.

Comment: on every restartLoaderManger, the method onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> arg0) will be invoked, in that method, in this callback method use notifyDataSetChagned.